# Spring boot app not starting with Maven & Karate

Tags: spring-boot, karate, junit5

I have a code like this and somehow when I am running through Intellij then it is starting the spring boot `ConsumeServiceApplication` application however when I am running it through maven then it's not starting the same Spring Boot Application.

Am I missing anything in pom.xml to add it?

```
import foo.ConsumeServiceApplication;
import com.intuit.karate.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.*;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {
        ConsumeServiceApplication.class}, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AcceptanceTestConfiguration.class})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class AtddTest {

    private static final String CUCUMBER_OUTPUT_DIR = "target/cucumber";

    @Test
    public void testMyService() throws Exception {
        Results results = Runner.parallel(getClass(), 5, CUCUMBER_OUTPUT_DIR);
        Assertions.assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount());
    }

}
```

Comment: sorry no idea, possibly your command to start maven is wrong, you can try follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: After struggling a lot, I found the solution, it was the issue with the Maven Surefire Plugin 
https://dzone.com/articles/why-your-junit-5-tests-are-not-running-under-maven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that none of the `SpringBootTest` were starting the Spring boot app, it was the issue with Maven Surefire Plugin

Details are at

https://dzone.com/articles/why-your-junit-5-tests-are-not-running-under-maven

Comment: Yes, I was able to solve by explicitly say I wanted to use failsafe and surefire version 2.22.0.   there might be other versions that work also.   I found that using Karate to call spring boot api during tests works great, and can even be wired into Gatling  (but don't use integration-test phase because I couldn't get that to work).

Answer (score 0):

To add more info to the answer of this question:

1. use `spring-boot-maven-plugin`   to wire up a spring boot server before your karate tests using  `mvn test`, which will work sufficiently for the purpose.
   You could use the example `https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/test/ServerStart.java` but in my opinion that is more complicated that it needs to be.
2. for Gatling performance tests with karate+spring-boot, you will need `gatling-maven-plugin`, in combination with `mvn verify`  and this snippet of code at the top of your .scala file:

```
// Because Maven Failsafe will not start Spring-Boot before the Gatling test, we hard code it.
  val app: ConfigurableApplicationContext = SpringApplication.run(classOf[MyApplication])
  Runtime.getRuntime.addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    override def run(): Unit = app.stop()
  })
```

Comment: in my opinion Maven is more complicated than it needs to be :)

Comment: Yeah, the Maven method wouldn't work if you wanted to use Karate standalone .jar for execution.